# Computer says you need permission for the owner to making changes to my Host file. All my computers are doing this. How do I Fix This?

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

When saving my host file an error comes back and says you need permission for the owner to make this change. All my computers are doing this. How I Fix this?

Comment: Try copying the `hosts` file to somewhere outside its original directory, make your changes, and then copy it back. Backing up the original `hosts` file under a different title may be advisable before proceeding (e.g. change its name to `hosts.original`).

Comment: “All my computers are doing this. How I Fix this?” - Open the text editor has an Administrator. There is nothing to fix, what you describe is completely expected, when your attempting to edit the hosts file on Windows as a user without elevated permissions

Comment: Either add your user to the ACL of `hosts` with Full Control permissions or the other suggestions of opening a text editor as Administrator _(I prefer the former over the latter, as it's more efficient)_

Answer (score 1):

The HOSTS file is secured (even for the owner).

Find Notepad, right click on it, and then select Run as Administrator.

Now in Notepad, navigate to HOSTS, change it (edit it) and save it.

The Edit and Save will work and this is entirely expected and normal.

Comment: `hosts` is owned by `System` and while ownership of files within `%WinDir%` should never be owned by a user, a user can give themselves full permissions to the file _(AFAIK, ownership of files within `%WinDir%`, even user-editable ones within `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc`, should never be changed)_

Answer (score 0):

As John said, HOSTS file is secured.

I did some trick to "ignore" that issue, maybe it helps:

Edit Hosts file (**MAKE A BACKUP OF THAT FILE BEFORE EDITING, ALWAYS!!**)

Save it to C:/Documents (or whatever path you'd like)

Copy that hosts file

Paste it where you are saving and gives error

Replace

Should be good to go

Comment: What would be the purpose of backing up `hosts` before editing?

Comment: Common practice, to backup a sensitive file before editing, like a registry file, I always advise to take a screenshot or back up those kind of files before doing something, you should always be able to "revert" any change you're doing, you never know what can happen when you're editing!

Comment: The `hosts` file isn't a critical system file and is not analogous to a Registry hive in it's importance. What mistake do you believe would happen when editing the `hosts` file and why would a backup be needed to revert such a mistake? _(This answer and subsequent reply makes it seem as though there may be a misunderstanding as to the purpose of the `hosts` file.)_

Comment: Had a boss that wanted to "block" sites like facebook, instagram, etc. With the genious idea that he didn't like users to "google" sites while at work (they had to use the Work App @ all times).. So he added google.com to the hosts file, sadly, the Work App used a Google Service to update itself, with that hosts file block it couldn't connect causing a loop.
We couldn't really find the problem until he told us that he was blocking sites.. The application didn't update every day, but when it tried to, it was blocked.

Comment: I'm not understanding how the reply applies to what I'm asking. `hosts` isn't a system critical file and is not even used by [default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default-c2a43f9d-e176-c6f3-e4ef-3500277a6dae) - `hosts` is only used when modified by the user to direct a specific IP/host name to a specific host name/IP [format: `<IP> <hostname> <hostname>.<localdomain>` || `<IP> <hostname>.<domain>`]

Comment: We're completely out of topic but you asked "What mistake do you believe would happen when editing the hosts file" I just stated an example of what DID happen when mistakingly editing hosts file. Hosts file isn't a critical system file, that is correct, I'm not arguing against that. I'm just saying that you can break things by modifying it, without wanting to do so.

Comment: The prior example was of someone who didn't do due diligence to determine if any services used were blocked by blocking content via the `hosts` file, which in and of itself has nothing to do with the `hosts` file since it operated as expected. My main point in all of this is such a disclaimer is unnecessary when the `hosts` file's default state is disabled and unused - in order to revert a previous change, simply comment out the line with a `#` or remove it entirely. Folks who use the `hosts` file are going to know what they're using it for, as it's not something that's edited just to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open notepad with a Right Click > Run As Administrator.

This will allow you to edit and save the hosts file without moving it. You'll need to reboot your computer for any changes you make to come into affect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems even if you are a member of local predefined group (as Administrators `S-1-5-32-544`) you won't be able to edit file due to UAC. For such built-in groups Windows requires the app to have elevated token: *only with such a token the group membership is taken into account*.

To workaround you can create artificial local group or grant user privilege directly to the file. Otherwise the only option is to run an app elevated.